# can not change the background color in createMeterialTopTabNavigator

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native

I am trying to change the color of the background in the tabs. I have created tabs using createMeterialTopTabNavigator from react-navigation-tabs. so far I Have tried using properties like activeBackgroundColor and inactiveBackgroundColor but its not working. I have included a screenshot. I would like to change the blue background color and the color of the line below ARENACASH which is only shown for active tab. FYI. activeTintColor and inactiveTintColor are working. which is how the color of  active tab is orange and inactive tab is black.

this is my code

```
import { Text, View} from 'react-native';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';

import {
  createBottomTabNavigator,
  createMaterialTopTabNavigator
} from "react-navigation-tabs";
import{createAppContainer} from "react-navigation";
import ArenaCashScreen from './Screens/ArenaCashScreen';
import ArenaPointsScreen from './Screens/ArenaPointsScreen';
import UnknownCashScreen from './Screens/UnknownCashScreen';


const MainTabs = createMaterialTopTabNavigator(
  {
    ArenaCash: ArenaCashScreen,
    ArenaPoints: ArenaPointsScreen,
    UnknownCash:UnknownCashScreen
  },
  {
    tabBarOptions: {
     activeTintColor: 'orange',
    activeBackgroundColor:'green',
    inactiveTintColor: 'black',
    inactiveBackgroundColor:'red',
    }
  }
);

const AppContainer = createAppContainer(MainTabs);

export default AppContainer;
```

My package.json is

```
{
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "eject": "expo eject"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "expo": "~37.0.3",
    "react": "~16.9.0",
    "react-dom": "~16.9.0",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-37.0.1.tar.gz",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.6.1",
    "react-native-material-dropdown": "^0.11.1",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^1.9.0",
    "react-native-screens": "^2.9.0",
    "react-native-snap-carousel": "^3.9.1",
    "react-native-web": "~0.11.7",
    "react-navigation": "^4.4.0",
    "react-navigation-stack": "^2.8.2",
    "react-navigation-tabs": "^2.9.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.8.6",
    "babel-preset-expo": "~8.1.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56886331/changing-creatematerialtoptabnavigator-default-styling

Comment: @Vishal Dhawan Yes, it solved my problem. thanks a bunch.